# "REPLACE" kind of persisting with Doctrine2 EntityManager

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, entitymanager

I have an entity which I need to persist if it does not exist and update/replace if it exists.

I don't want to lookup using `->findBy()` and perform update or new operations.

With Doctrine1 you could simply make a new entity and use the method `->replace();` instead of `->save();`. I kinda need this behaviour for Doctrine2 using the EntityManager.

```
<?php
$user = new User;
$user->setName('Mr.Right');
$em->persist($user);
$em->flush();
```

From http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#persisting-entities :

> If X is a preexisting managed entity, it is ignored by the persist
>   operation.

I need preexisting managed entities to be replaced/updated, not ignored,
does anybody know?

Comment: have you ever found an answer to this?

Comment: @PavelDubinin nope, but to be honest I quit looking for a solution long ago

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure it's possible without executing a raw query. But why don't you want to look it up first? I'd use the following:

```
$user = $em->find('User', $id);
if (!$user) {
    $user = new User;
    $em->persist($user);
}
$user->setName('Mr.Right');
$em->flush();
```

Comment: This is what I have atm but if you have 200k entities, it's a little faster to use 200k x a single `REPLACE` instead of 200k x `SELECT` + `if` + `UPDATE`/`INSERT`

Comment: The reason replace isn't supported (anymore?) is probably because not all platforms support it. Either use a raw query for batch processing or have a look at http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/batch-processing.html

Comment: hmm okay.. will do some more reasearch or simply use a `find`. +1 for your effort and help, thank you!